# FCM rich push notification payload for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `FCM` for my project. It's have rich push notification for a type. I tried to modified most of possible ways to get push from `FCM`. I got obly ordinary push from `FCM`, not with image.

I am also check with APNS same coding using [push try](http://pushtry.com/). I got what expected design for push notification.

Here my `APNS` payload

```
{
  "aps": {
     "alert": "Enter your message",
     "badge": 1,
     "sound": "default",
     "content-available": 1,
     "mutable-content": 1
  },
  "mediaUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG"
}
```

Here `FCM` payload

```
{
   "to": "dWB537Nz1GA:APA91bHIjJ5....",
   "data":
   {
      "message": "Offer!",
      "mediaUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG"
   },
   "notification":
   {
      "body": "Enter your message",
      "sound": "default",
      "content-available": 1,
      "mutable-content": 1
   }
}
```

Also I am need category [more details about payload in FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

Am I missing any setting in fire-base console or is that from payload.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `mutable-content` and `content-available` in your FCM payload is incorrect. It should be formatted as `mutable_content` and `content_available`. Both are *boolean* and must also be outside the `notification` parameter. Like so:

```
{
   "to": "dWB537Nz1GA:APA91bHIjJ5....",
   "content_available": true,
   "mutable_content": true,
   "data":
   {
      "message": "Offer!",
      "mediaUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG"
   },
   "notification":
   {
      "body": "Enter your message",
      "sound": "default"
   }
}
```

For the counterpart of `category` in FCM, you should use [`click_action`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support):

> The action associated with a user click on the notification.
>
> Corresponds to **category** in the APNs payload.

Comment: @AL. Is this the right FCM payload? I mean why message and body are separated? Can't it be both in notification or both in data ? It feels not right to me to have the title and message of the notification in a separated { }

Comment: @Balanced Its a valid payload. However, what you did mention is also valid. It all deoends on your use-case.

Comment: can we pass dictionary in payload ?
 "to" : “device token”,
     "content_available": true,
    "notification" : {

    },
    "data": {
    "payload" : {
      "dataa": {
        "btn_action": “Some text“, 
        "lock_mac" : "0Some text",
        "device_type" : "iOS",
        “some key” : "Some text"
      }
    }
  }
  }

Comment: @Developer The `data` message payload caters to custom data. So yes. Just makw sure you handle it properly. Cheers!

Comment: AL. func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

userInfo["payload"] as? [String:Any] is always nil in the above function

Comment: @Developer I would suggest posting a question with the corresponding codes and details so that the community could help you better. :)

Comment: Is this "mutable-content" to "mutable_content" mapping documented anywhere? 
 I'm not finding it.

Comment: @Krum https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me. The accepted answer seems to have some unnecessary information.

```
{
  "to" : "devicekey OR /topics/sometopic",
  "mutable_content": true,
  "data": {
    "mymediavideo": "https://myserver.com/myvideo.mp4"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "my title",
    "subtitle": "my subtitle",
    "body": "some body"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please ask the author of the accepted answer to improve his answer with this information.

Comment: [Check this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531730/fcm-rich-push-notification-payload-for-ios/50485313#comment85633039_42533430)