# firebase notification alert after click

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this code to get an alert when a notification arrives. If the app is in the background, I see the tab and click on it. If the app is killed, it does not work. What should I do?

I'm working with iOS 10 and Firebase.

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "you have a new notification", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
        }
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        ...
     }
```

Comment: Please provide more details--"does not work" is too vague. Also, try to post a stripped-down version of the code that we can copy/paste and test on our own machines.

Answer (score 0):

I understood from your question that,

- Case 1 : App shows notification banner when app runs in Foreground.
- Case 2 : App will not show notification banner when app killed or in Background.

In fact, for both cases we have to handle separately.
Lets skip for Case 1 because it works fine !! Cheers..

**For the case 2, there might be below reason(s) that might cause above issue.**

> 1. Payload JSON received from Server is not as per FCM standard structure. 
>      For example : To activate notification delegate when app is in background, FCM payload
>      json must contain `"content_available": true` [Example payload found
>      from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531730/fcm-rich-push-notification-payload-for-ios)
> 2. In your Project Capabilities > Background Mode> Remote-notification option must be
>      selected. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)