# Appcelerator iOS Rich Push Notification not showing image when sent through FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, appcelerator

I am trying to send the rich notification in my iOS App. I am using the FCM to send the notification. Below is the payload as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42533430/7420795). I am using FCM Module(https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-cloud-messaging). I am referring [this](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ios-push-notifications) sample project and successfully added `UNNotificationServiceExtension` in my Titanium project. 
But the problem here is that, I am receiving normal Notification only, image is not visible in the notification panel.

```
{
    "to": "e4DgI95lsPA:APA91bHFX9MUmJ....",
    "content_available": true,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "click_action": "DOWNLOAD_CONTENT",
    "data": {
        "message": "Offer!",
        "attachment-url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/FloorGoban.JPG/1024px-FloorGoban.JPG"
    },
    "notification": {
        "body": "Enter your message",
        "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the README of the linked github example:
`Rich Notifications are part of the Titanium SDK 7.2.0 release`

The current SDK version is 7.1.1.GA. So it will only work if you are using the nightly builds or a custom SDK

Comment: Hello @miga , GA release of Ti SDK 7.2.0 will take time for release I think. Can't we do anything with current solution? Because I am getting the Notification with the mentioned solution, just not getting Image in the Notification. Is there anything I am missing in my setup or doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I understood the text the feature you want (image) is part of that release and not available before. So if you really need it try the nightly builds from http://builds.appcelerator.com/

Comment: I am able to receive the Notification with image with mentioned settings. I achieved it by specifying two params 
`"attachment-url": "https://api.buienradar.nl/Image/1.0/RadarMapNL",
    "attachment-name": "example.png` in above mentioned payload. But when I replace the URL of `attachment-url` I am unable to receive it.