# How to create Payload for Rich Text Notification using FCM

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing Rich Text Notification in one of my app. I know that I need the payload in the following format:

```
{
  "aps": {
      "alert": {
          "title": "", 
          "body": “”
      },
      "badge": 1,
      "sound": "default",
      "mutable-content": true,
      "content-available": true,
      "category": "defaultCategory"
  },
  "image_url": ""
}
```

Although when I tried with default APNS process I did it successfully, but I just faced a issue while implementing it using FCM, and problem is that I am not receiving the keys:

```
mutable-content: 1
category: defaultCategory
```

I explored about it and found a url [FCM rich push notification payload for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531730/fcm-rich-push-notification-payload-for-ios/42533430?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
, I tried with the mentioned keys as well.

```
"mutable_content": true,
"click_action": defaultCategory,
```

But even using these I am not getting correct result. Current payload I am receiving after final changes are:

```
{
    gcm.notification.category: defaultCategory, 
    image: /r/u/rustyredsmall.jpg, 
    type_id: XMH677878912-L-Blue, 
    type: Product, 
    aps: {
        alert =     {
           body = "new product notification message2018-05-24 00:00:00";
           title = "Product Notification";
        };
       badge = 1;
       sound = default;
    }, 
    0: {"mutable_content":true}, 
    gcm.message_id: 0:1527142412430945%98b85c5198b85c51
}
```

Any suggestion, how I can get the correct payload?

Comment: Your payload is not structured correctly, and that would probably because it was not initially built correctly. Do you have the code or the process you're using to build the payload? If so, can you include it in the question? There are a number of issues as it includes- default, an array and some other items that don't have correct values or placement in the structure. Oh - you should investigate the value of the sound key as the word *default* is probably where things are going awry. That should probably be quoted text *"default"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I debugged the issue and resolved the issue successfully, there are some ***problem with the key placement at sever end***. We have created the payload at server end as:

```
{
    "to”: “xyz”,
    "mutable_content": true,
    "notification":
        {
            "body": “this is the message body.“,
            "title": “tiltle text”,
            "sound": "default",
            "badge": 1,
            "click_action": "defaultCategory"
        },
    "data":
        {
            "type": "Category",
            "typeId": "74",
            "redirect_title": "",
            "image_url": "\/d\/r\/dress_16.jpg",
            "notification_id": "1"
        }
}
```

***FCM formatted this payload and sent it to mobile end in the following format:***

```
{
    gcm.message_id: “0:1527233474081223%98b85c5198b85c51”, 
    aps: {
        alert: {
            body: "new product notification message2018-05-24 00:00:00";
            title: "Product Notification";
        };
        badge: 1;
        category: “defaultCategory”;
        mutable-content: 1;
        sound: “default”;
    }, 
    notification_id: 11, 
    typeId: “XMH677878912-L-Blue”, 
    image_url: “/r/u/rustyredsmall.jpg”, 
    type: “Product”, 
    redirect_title: “Midi Dress-L-Blue”
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh Man! You are a life saver. This ---> "click_action": "defaultCategory" parameter as "category":"defaultCategory" has worked for me... Thank you so much!